# Excel date format mismatch

Tags: excel, date

I have a huge excel file with one column containing the date. The problem is that the date in this column is in different formats as shown below:

```
12/5/17 
12/5/17 
15-05-17 0:00
19-05-17 0:00
19-05-17 0:00
22-05-17 0:00
```

Some have a time stamp in that, some are in dd/mm/yy or mm/dd/yy format. I need a single format mm/dd/yy form(no time stamp). I did try the basic methods, like formatting the cell (going to the category, choosing a single date format but for the values of m/d/yy h:mm;@ is not changing).
I further tried using datevalue, to get the value in a new column by using the following formula: =DATEVALUE(MONTH(D2) & "/" & DAY(D2) & "/" & YEAR(D2))
Again, it is not working. Any ideas to fix this shall be highly appreciated?
Thanks

Comment: What kind of a file is this? Did it come from a CSV file? If so, you need to obtain the original csv file, and then IMPORT it into Excel. If you do that, the text import wizard will open and you can instruct Excel as to the format of the date column in the original CSV file (probably MDY), not the format you want in your worksheet.  That you do after the date in the CSV file has been properly interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks very much as if the "dates" are text, because they show in so many different formats.

Select the dates, click Data > Text to columns > Next > Next. In Step 3 of the wizard, mark the column as a Date column and from the dropdown select the order that the source data is in, i.e. DMY. Then hit Finish and the dates will show as dates using the format of your regional settings.

[image]

Now you can strip the time by using a helper column with the INT() function, or just format the values to show without the time.

Comment: Thanks for your solution @teylyn. Unfortunately for the dates with - is still showing the same.

Comment: I gave this solution based on the sample data you posted. If that does not work with your real data, you need to share some of your real data in a real file. Please share a sample file. Use a file sharing service like OneDrive or DropBox. No sites that require login or registration or payment to download, please.